# Generic is an abstract class in python?

Tags: python, generics, abstract-class, crud, type-variables

I'm trying to create a base class that works for any CRUD in applications and I've seen the following implementation:

```
ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=Base)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
```

```
class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[ModelType]):
        """CRUD object with default methods to Create, Read, Update,
        Delete (CRUD).
        **Parameters**
        * `model`: A SQLAlchemy model class
        * `schema`: A Pydantic model (schema) class
        """
        self.model = model

    '...crud methods'`
```

Generic is a way to define an abstract class, containing the objects that are specified (in this case [ModelType,CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]) or what is the use of generic?

Comment: Not sure what your real question is here. A generic does not necessarily need to be abstract. Neither does an abstract class have to be generic. Those two concepts sometimes overlap, but they are distinct. Please be more specific. What exactly do you not understand? And only ask one question at a time. Also _"is there a better way"_ is extremely vague. The answer is most certainly yes, no matter the context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your observations. Specifically, I would like to know in this case what is the use of generic? Is it to indicate the type of variables that the class should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about the purpose of [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) I would suggest you read through [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484). It has a section dedicated to [user defined generic classes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) with some examples specifically for this, but the entire document is worthwhile reading IMHO. If you are unsure about the entire concept of generic types, the  Wikipedia articles on [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) and [generic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) might even be worth skimming.

In very simple terms, you can use the `Generic` base class to define your own classes in a generic way, i.e. parameterized with regards to one or more type  arguments. These type parameters are constructed via [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). It is worth noting that in most cases these things are only relevant for the purposes of type safety, which is not really enforced by Python itself. Instead, static type checkers (most IDEs have them built-in) deal with those things.

As to your example, it is entirely possible to define your class in a generic way and thus improve your own coding experience because you'll likely get useful auto-suggestions and warnings by your IDE. This only really becomes useful, if you use the type variables somewhere else throughout your class. Example:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Base:
    pass


ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=Base)


class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[ModelType]):
        self.model = model

    def get_model_instance(self) -> ModelType:
        return self.model()


class Sub(Base):
    def foo(self) -> None:
        print("hi mom")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    crud_a = CRUDBase(Sub)
    crud_b = CRUDBase(Base)
    a = crud_a.get_model_instance()
    b = crud_b.get_model_instance()
    a.foo()
    b.foo()  # error
```

A good type checker like `mypy` will know, that `a` is of the `Sub` type and thus has the `foo` method, whereas `b` is of the `Base` type and therefore does *not*. And it will know so just from the way we annotated `CRUDBase`.

PyCharm for example struggles with this (don't know why). Fortunately, we can help it out with explicit type annotations because we defined `CRUDBase` as a generic type:

```py
...
    crud_a: CRUDBase[Sub] = CRUDBase(Sub)
    crud_b: CRUDBase[Base] = CRUDBase(Base)
    a = crud_a.get_model_instance()
    b = crud_b.get_model_instance()
    a.foo()
    b.foo()  # PyCharm marks `foo` and complains
```

Notice that so far there is nothing particularly "abstract" about our `CRUDBase`. It is fully self-contained and functioning like this (albeit not very useful yet).

If you want a class to be an abstract base and not be directly instantiated, the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) module provides you with the tools you need. You can define an abstract base class and [abstract methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) on it that all subclasses *must* implement. But I think it is clear now that this is a different concept. The idea is that an abstract class is not intended to be instantiated, only its subclasses are.

I hope this helps point you in a few useful directions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a much more comprehensive answer than I would have imagined getting. People like you make this community a powerful tool for everyone!